# jekyll variables, if functions

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Why is something like this not working ?
i try to filter all posts from this year

```
<div class="tiles">
{% for post in site.categories.articles %}

  {% capture pubyear %} {{ post.date | date: "%Y" }} {% endcapture %}

    {% if pubyear == "2014" %}
      {% include post-grid.html %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</div><!-- /.tiles -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it is capturing the output with some spaces in it, so it fails the if condition, remove those spaces and it should work

```
<div class="tiles"> 
  {% for post in site.categories.articles %}
    {% capture pubyear %}{{ post.date | date: "%Y" }}{% endcapture %} 
    {% if pubyear == "2014" %} 
      {% include post-grid.html %} 
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: so i compare to
{% if pubyear == " 2014 " %}

Comment: Well I would remove the spaces between the capture tag and post.date,  in the example I have removed them there.

Comment: @wwwSammy if you remove them inside capture, compare to "2014", or if you don't remove them, compare to " 2014 ". Just try and select what works for you

Comment: You can use `{%- capture -%}` to minimize white space in liquid

Answer (score 1):

Capturing the pubyear is vaild but you can also assign pubyear with no spaces.

`{% assign pubyear = post.date | date: "%Y" %}`